# rotating ik target bones

Tags: rigging

I was wondering if I can make IK bones rotate gradually. I have a dragon with quite a few IK target bones to allow for a wonderful flow with his tail. As you can see when I rotate the hip all the bones move with it like it should. Can I have it do a gradual rotation with those bones as if gravity is helping keep it down. I have tried copy rotations on them but it doesn't do it. [!
[[[image: ][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJJeF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWn8R.png)

Comment: No, you cannot simulate physical effects, which occur over time, with rigging.  (In earlier versions you had slow parents which could be abused for this purpose, but they were buggy and so they're gone.)  If you want anything like gravity or inertia, you need to be using physics simulations to acquire it.

Comment: thanks for the responce.